# Is there a way to change the message "press ENTER or type command to continue" to something else?

Tags: terminal, external-command, shell

I would like to change it to make something like a separator between `!python %`

Change this(my computer is in spanish):

[image]

To something like:

```
Hello World

---------------
Hello World

---------------
```

All I have found are answers to disable it but not to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik this string is hardcoded into vim (and translated).

You would have to patch and recompile vim yourself.

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/94b6fb78c578caab014fea4029bb534246a95f6f/src/po/es.po#L4914) (thanks @Rich).

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/94b6fb78c578caab014fea4029bb534246a95f6f/src/po/es.po#L4914

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, thanks!